# Best practice for handling mysql connection in a social network system

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Currently, I am dealing with a social network startup. We use php & mysql for back-end development. I have a datamanager.php that have functions which handles the sql connections and queries. I have several functions like signup, login, get_profile, etc.

I have 2 choices for handling mysql connection

1) create a globally reachable `$connection` variable with `mysqli_connect();` and don't close the connections until I finish all the database operations.

2) create a function namely `db_connect()` that returns the connection variable in each database functions. Also, in each database function like login, signup, I close the connection with `mysqli_close();` and get another connection variable with `db_connect();`

So, which choice is better for handling mysql connections and why ?

Comment: Use a framework, start reading zend framework

Comment: Discussion on this: https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-connection-handling-and-scaling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to keep the MySQL connection open as of performance. Better use a class to handle all mysql connections and somehow pass the instance of the class (i.e. the object itself) to all other functions/classes which need it. Within the class you could establish the connection ONCE and than keep it!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, on the assumption that you are building something that needs to have a long shelf life, and scale to lots of users, with a roadmap for new features, I'd encourage you to use an off-the-shelf PHP framework; Zend or Symfony seem to be the front runners. These frameworks provide a lot of the plumbing for you, so you won't have to worry about database connections.

However, specifically answering your question, I'd encourage you to use **[mysql_pconnect](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php)** - it frees you up from worrying about opening and closing connections. You do need to read the manual, it's not totally straightforward...